# Python - Identify certain keywords in a user's input, to then lead to an answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python - Identify certain keywords in a user's input, to then lead to an answer. For example, user inputs "There is no display on my phone"

The keywords 'display' and 'phone' would link to a set of solutions.

I just need help finding a general idea on how to identify and then lead to a set of solutions. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Basically you have a vague idea of what you want and no idea of how to do it. Therefore, SO is probably not the best place to ask. I would suggest you read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page first so that you can ask a good question following SO standards and get the chance to receive a proper answer that would then be useful to others

Answer (score 0):

Use NLTK library, import stopwords.
write a code that if the word in your text is in stopword then you have to remove that word. You will get the filtered output.

Also,
Make a negative list file - containing all the words apart from stopwords that you want to remove, extent the stopwords with these words before the above code.and you will get a 100% correct output.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way if you don't want to use any external libraries would be the following.

```
def bool_to_int(list):
    num = 0
    for k, v in enumerate(list):
        if v==1:
            num+=(2**k)
    return num

def take_action(code):
    if code==1:
        # do this
    elif code==2:
        # do this
    ...


keywords = ['display', 'phone', .....,]
list_of_words = data.split(" ")
code = [0]*len(keywords)
for i in list_of_words:
    if i in keywords:
        idx = keywords.index(i)
        code[idx]=1
code = bool_to_int(code)
take_action(code)
```